# How to get the attributes override properties?

Tags: .net, reflection, attributes, properties, virtual

Does not work [Attribute.GetCustomAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs2dx40d.aspx):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var p = typeof(MyClass2).GetProperty("Value");
        var a = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(ObsoleteAttribute), true);
        Console.WriteLine(a != null);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    [Obsolete]
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass2 : MyClass
{
    public override string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Output: False

Why?

Comment: What happens if you change MyClass2 to MyClass when obtaining the property?

Comment: In this case works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [`ObsoleteAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx) you'll see that its `AttributeUsage` sets [`Inherited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.inherited.aspx) to false - so the attribute isn't inherited by overriding members.

I suspect if you check that it's overriding a base property and work your way up the inheritance chain, you'll be able to discover the attribute that way. It's a bit of a mess doing this sort of thing, admittedly.